# Can't delete records from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a program that will receive values through URL and then will either add an entry to the MySQL database, delete it or if someone else has booked that slot then it will not let you delete it.

The add and delete functions are as follows:

```
function addBooking($id, $desk, $member, $date){
    global $dbconn;
    $query = $dbconn -> prepare("INSERT INTO booked (booking_id, desk_id, member_id, date_booked) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $query -> bind_param("iiis", $id, $desk, $member, $date);
    $query->execute();
    print '<div class="yours" title="Your Booking">Your Booking</div>';
    $query -> close();
}

function delBooking($id, $desk){
    global $dbconn;
    $query = $dbconn -> prepare("DELETE FROM booked WHERE booking_id = ? AND desk_id = ?");
    $query -> bind_param("ii", $id, $desk);
    $query->execute();
    print '<div class="free" title="Click To Book">Not Booked</div>';
    $query -> close();
}
```

And the code that calls them is this:

```
$query = $dbconn -> prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, booked.member_id, date_booked FROM members, booked WHERE (members.member_id = booked.member_id) AND booking_id = ? AND desk_id=?");
    $query -> bind_param("ss", $booking_id, $desk_id);
    if($query->execute() == true) {
        $query -> bind_result($fname, $lname, $memid, $dbooked);
        $query -> fetch();
        if($fname){
            if ($memid == $member_id)
            {
                delBooking($booking_id,$desk_id);
            }
            else
            {
                print '<div class="taken" title="Booked by <strong>'.$fname.' '.$lname.'</strong><br>On '.$dbooked.'">Booked</div>';
            }
        }else{
            addBooking($booking_id,$desk_id,$member_id,$date);
        }
    }
```

It adds a booking fine and will also tell you if someone else has booked it fine, but if you run it again on your own booking it will give you the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/new/functions/functions.php on line 80
```

I'm not sure why. It's not my delete statement or anything because I can rename the addBooking function to delBooking so it's identical working code and it still gives me exactly the same error :/

Comment: is $query -> bind_param("ss", $booking_id, $desk_id); the 80-th line in functions.php?

Comment: Yes. Sorry should have mentioned that.

Comment: and what your PDO::ERRMODE set to? (PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT;PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING;PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)

Comment: As the error suggests your `prepare` statement probably fails. Try `var_dump($query)` right after `prepare`

Comment: mysqli::prepare returns either prepared statement object or false. In your case prepare probably fails.

Comment: Make sure all the **individual columns** in your query are unique (meaning, there isn't any with the same name in the other table) - `firstname`, `lastname`, `date_booked`, `booking_id`, `desk_id`. It will return false instead of a resource, also when the query is not well written.

Comment: Did you try to execute your `SELECT` query in mysql using some ids? As inhan pointed out it's more than likely that some of columns are not unique.

Comment: when I do a var_dump($query) it says it's false.
But here's the strange thing. If I make the second click even if it's booked  run the same addBooking function, exactly the same call as the one that books it, it returns false too. Nothing changes. The code is EXACTLY the same.

Comment: inhan, what do you mean make sure all of them are unique? They can't all be unique. The same person has to be able to book multiple slots. That's ridiculous to say they ALL have to be unique.

Comment: Columns, I wrote, not rows or column values. I meant column names.

Comment: And yes I ran the query in MySQL and it ran exactly as it should. The query is fine. The variables being passed to it are fine.

Comment: [**`mysqli_stmt_error()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php)

Comment: I say to it "If the slot is not booked, run this - addBooking($booking_id,$desk_id,$member_id,$date);" and it books the slot, works perfectly. I also say "If it IS booked, run exactly the same command - addBooking($booking_id,$desk_id,$member_id,$date);" and it fails. It works the first time, but not the second.

Comment: Just a check but, Are you intentionally calling delBooking() with 4 arguments even though only 2 arguments are enamed in the function definition?

Comment: Sorry, the code I pasted was from when I changed it to addBooking to test if that worked and just renamed it here instead of changing it back to it's original call with only 2 arguments.

Comment: You will need to output the error to see what goes wrong. Right after the call to prepare: if($query === false) {printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $dbconn->error);}

Comment: Errormessage: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now ?!

Comment: It looks like you would need to free the result http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Comment: but there IS no results yet!

Comment: Do you have any other queries in the same scope in the script that uses the functions that are defined before what you show us?

Comment: I tell ya what, if I upload the whole code will you have a look at it and see if you can see what's wrong? Because I've been staring at the same single line for over an hour.

Comment: Here's what's weird now. I just got it working, kinda. Not elegant or anything. By making a duplicate $dbconn, $dbconn2 it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using mysqli, you cannot have more than one prepared statement active on a single connection at the same time.  By active I mean is has been sent over to the server by calling it's execute() at least once.  You can have as many unused statements prepared, but you can only execute on one at a time.  When done, you need to close the statement before you execute another.  Before you call delBooking() close the earlier statement:

```
$query->fetch();
$query->close();
if($memid == $member_id){
    delBooking(....);
```